# Creating Dynamic Range based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to create dynamic ranges based on cell values contained in column A.  There are many ranges on the same sheet and the size of each range will change, thus I cannot identify a cell as the starting point for a range, since it will change.  I have a list of the different range names in column A of Sheet 2, which I can use to create the different ranges if needed. I'm thinking the best way to do this is using find, but again, I'm very new to this. Here's what I have so far (not much, I know). Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
 Sub NameRange()

Dim rngselect As Range, FinalRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("OOE")
Set rngselect = ws.Range("$A:Z")

ws.Columns(i, 1).Find(California).Select
.Name = "Cali"

End Sub
```

Comment: What values are in column A? That is, how do they indicate to you which range you want?

Comment: They are names, such as California, midwest. It indicates the category for the data in the rest of the row. Does that answer your question?

Comment: If California is a string, not a variable, it should be written as `"California"`

Comment: Oh, so you want to create named ranges? I misunderstood and thought you wanted to input range strings in A to help you determine range like `A1:D10`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct Kyle. Sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Have you tried just using Excel's create names function?  In code it would be something like `Worksheets("OOE").Range("A1:Z60").CreateNames Top:=False, Left:=True, Bottom:=False, Right:=False`.  ("Z60" used assuming you want range names created for the first 60 rows.  Change as necessary.)  From the menu it would be Formulas / Create from Selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this before and it's not as simple as it sounds. Named ranges are properties of the entire workbook and therefore must be unique. VBA will NOT generate an error if you change the range of a name (nor will it notify you).

With that being said, 
- don't select the range there is no need.
- since you are restricted to column A use a loop in case the find value is in column B

```
' Worksheet with names
Dim name_ws as Worksheet
' Assuming you're worksheet with the names is in the same workbook and named "Names"
Set name_ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Names")

' Find might be better but I haven't had my coffee so you'll get the double loop
for j = 1 to name_ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
   for i = 1 to ws.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
      if ws.Cell(i, 1) = name_ws.Cells(j, 2) then _
         Range(ws.Cell(i,1), ws.Cell(i, 26)).Name = name_ws.Cells(j, 1)
   next i
next j
```

**Please note**: ws is your variable and you don't specify the start and end cell of your Named range in the question so I just went 26 cells over.

**Please note**: I am assuming Column B of the worksheet with the names contains the search variable and Column A contains the name you want to use

Comment: Thanks J Reid. I got the following error, "Compile error: Method of data member not found".  Is there also a way to point the code to the other worksheet that contains each name so that it creates the ranges by that instead of copying this code and changing the name for each range?

Comment: Hi Ashley, I've edited the code. Should've added a new one because I am curious about that 'Compile error'. Did you keep Set ws = Worksheets("OOE")???

Comment: Actually I just realized it seems to replace the name each time until the last row. So once the macro has finished, the only named row is the last one. Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your data?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't as it's sensitive. I think the problem is that you can't have multiple ranges with the same name, so each time the function loops , it just overwrites the previous range with that name?

Comment: I feel good helping out with the sensitive stuff, lol!  
No two ranges can have the same name that is a fact. I didn't test this code but you can step through it with F8 to identify any problems. As stated above code in answer, names must be unique. What it does is move the name to the new range, if that makes sense.