# Creating muliple ranges based on criteria in column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

New to VBA, and I'm trying to create multiple ranges or arrays based on a criteria in a column, then place those in a separate worksheet. The issue is that this code has to work for several different data sets. So one data sat will look something like 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYJV5.png), but with far more data points ( around 10,000 for each data set).

So what I'm trying to do is, for each group of 1's in the state column, create a range/array, then move the corresponding time and data in a new worksheet. So for the example I have, there would be 3 new worksheets, with the first new worksheet containing range("A2:B5"), the second one containing range("A10:B12"). With each data set, the state column changes and the number of new worksheets can also vary.

I have looked through this site, and the closest I have found to my needs is [Creating Dynamic Range based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39906143/creating-dynamic-range-based-on-cell-value), but it has a known number of ranges. I quite honestly have no idea how to accomplish what I need. I've been trying to make a while loop inside of a if then loop inside of a for each loop, but can't make it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Been banging my head for hours now.

Comment: Are you only ever looking at State `1` and ignoring all other states?

Comment: Yeah there's only 2 states, and I only need state 1 to be moved

Comment: Why don't you give us some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should help you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim area As Range

    With Sheets("myDataSheet") '<--| reference your sheet (change "myDataSheet") to your actual sheet name
        With .Range("C1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:C range form row 1 down to last column A not empty row
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="1" '<--| filter referenced range on its 3rd column (i.e. "State") with 1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filterd cells other than header
                For Each area In .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 2).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas '<--| loop through filtered range (skipping header) 'Areas'
                    area.Copy Sheets.Add(Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Range("A1") '<--| copy current 'Area' into new sheet
                Next area
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! The new sheets are made and the ranges are right. My last remaining issue is that the area copied over only includes the first column, but I need both columns with data and time in them to be moved over.

Comment: see edited code. if it solved your question then please mark answer as accepted. thank you!

Comment: Amazing! Never expected a reply this quick! Thanks!